# Adding a superscript font awesome icon using CSS classes

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the following snippet of HTML..

```
<ul>
    <li class="fa fa-balance-scale" id="test" />
</ul>
```

..with the associated CSS classes:

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa-balance-scale:before {
    /* font-awesome: balance-scale */
    content: "\f24e"
}

.fa-hourglass-2:before,
.fa-hourglass-half::before {
    /* font awesome: balance-scale, fa-hourglass-half */
    content: "\f24e \f252";
}

.fa-lg {
    font-size: 1.33333333em;
    line-height: .75em;
    vertical-align: -15%;
}
```

..and some JS to increase the size and append an hourglass after an event:

```
$("#test").addClass("fa-hourglass-half fa-lg")
```

..and I am looking to create the following (image):

[image: desired result]

Whilst I have managed it using the following...

```
<i class="fa" icon-before="&#xf24e" icon-after="&#xf252"></i>

i:before {
    /*balance-scale*/
    content: attr(icon-before);
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0.1em;
}

i:after {
    /*fa-hourglass-half*/
    content: attr(icon-after);
    position: absolute;
    font-size: -0.5em;
    /*margin-bottom: 2.0em;*/
}
```

...it is not appropriate as I need to use CSS classes only. This is due to dependencies (and ensure compatibility) with other components of the application I am working on.

Is there anyone who can propose a possible solution using only CSS classes? Any advice or suggestions would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

With thanks to all and especially sheriffderek, this is the code which was used:

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa.loading {
    position: relative;
}

.fa.loading:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: -12px;
    content: '\f252';
    transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
}

.fa-lg {
    font-size: 1.33333333em;
    line-height: .75em;
    vertical-align: -15%;
}
```

Comment: did you load the font-awesome library ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/oeoGZV it seems to work in FF

Comment: "Whilst I have managed it using the following... ...it is not appropriate as I need to use CSS classes only" <- this could be much clearer.

Comment: why not use 2 <i> tags with their respective class to load the needed font as meant to be used ? you can style them without  the need of updating :before content. while the rule already stands in the font-awesome css file.  negative font-size do not exist btw ;)

Comment: I use svg sprites instead - but I think that using the <i> (although a hack) - is much more semantically correct. ALSO... `<li>` are not self closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for an official 'font-awesome' way, I don't know it - but here's the logic behind how I'd try and do it.

First I would create a jsFiddle - and make sure that the font and other dependencies are loaded / so we're all on the same page: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/rqLkjmo3/2/   --- it looks like this link: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css  includes the @font inclusion and the css.

Then I would create some functionality to check:

```
<ul class='icon-list'>
  <li class='icon fa fa-camera-retro' id='test'></li>
</ul>

<button rel='toggle'>toggle superscript</button>
```

jQuery in this case:

```
var $button = $('[rel="toggle"]');

$button.on('click', function() {
    $('#test').toggleClass('waiting');
});
```

And then lay over something - in the top corner / is this font-awesome specific? / is there an hourglass-version of 'balance-scale' ? I don't know. I couldn't get .fa-balance-scale to work...

```
.icon-list {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.fa.waiting {
  position: relative;
}

.fa.waiting:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: 'x'; /* whatevers */
  color: red;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

This logic should work for any type of graphic inclusion. Icons fonts were great when they were the best option, but that is no longer the case. Take a look at fontastic or something that will spit out a sprite sheet. : )

Comment: Thank you for your help. Whilst it was not quite what I was looking for, your answer helped me enormously and pointed me in the right direction.